# Rapid Sight Acquisition

Tags: battlefield-3, battlefield-4

In Battlefield 4, the description of TRI BEAM LASER is as follows:

> Triple Beam laser sight that provides the normal benefits of a laser
>   sight, but with three individual dots for rapid sight acquisition.

Now we all know that all laser sights improve the weapon's hip fire accuracy by reducing the weapon's hip fire spread and have a blinding effect on enemies when up close. But I've been wondering from the times when Battlefield 3 came up, what "rapid sight acquisition" means in weapons terminology.

Does the laser beam "stick" to the enemies that are very very close to (but NOT on) your crosshairs? Does it guide you even by a little amount by rapidly acquiring targets automatically?

Please don't just say "No", provide some facts and evidence.

Comment: From my experience - the tri beam laser is just a fancier version of the normal laser. It doesn't guide you or stick to close enemies. The "rapid sight acquisition" seems to be just flavour text, to make it look more "tacticool".

Comment: It just makes you feel more predator like, while also making you be seen across the map ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## In Real Life...

*Sight acquisition means transitioning your focus from the target to the sight of your weapon in order to shoot.*

[image: Proper front sight focus, the front sight is in focus and the rear sight and target are blurry]

A scoped weapon puts the target and the crosshairs in the same vertical plane.  There's no choice of what to focus on.  An iron sighted weapon, however, has three distinct vertical planes - the rear sight, the front sight, and the target.  The human eye can only focus in one plane at a time.

[image: Impossible focus]
This is **impossible**.

The human eye can't focus on both the target and the sights at the same time.

[image: Correct focus]
This is **correct**.

When shooting, this is the picture your eye should see.  The front sight should be in sharp focus, with the rear sights slightly blurry and the target slightly blurry.

Laser sights put the "front sight" in the same vertical plane as the target, however, your focus should still be on the sight.  Transition from focusing on the target to focusing on the sight, then, while keeping the sight on the target, apply pressure to the trigger until the gun fires.

## In the game...

All targets are by definition in the same vertical plane - your screen.  Therefore, the game engine takes care of focus for you, always keeping either the target or the sights in focus as appropriate.  In this case, **sight acquisition simply means being able to distinguish the sights**.  It's flavor text, nothing more, because your eyes aren't really seeing the game in 3-D.

Comment: Wow man, thank you, you nearly made me feel ashamed to have bothered you and it feels like I stole your time :)

Comment: @Anar - Among other things, I'm a competitive target shooter.  You didn't bother me, you gave me an easy one. :]

Comment: This is an amazing answer. +1 for you sir.